# Add Conditional Format to datagrid when equal two columns

Tags: php, phpgrid

I have a table on phpGrid, there is function for adding conditional format on the cells but i need more adaptive option... when in any rows tow defined cells equals each others i want to add format

For example when in any row n cell nR == nT i want to make them red colors

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders"); 
$dg->set_conditional_format("orderNumber","CELL",array( "condition"=>"eq","value"=>"10107","css"=> array("color"=>"#ffffff","background-color"=>"green"))); 
// that is in documentation and i have tried this 
$dg->set_conditional_format("orderNumber","CELL",array( "condition"=>"eq","value"=>$dg->columns['orderNumber'] ,"css"=> array("color"=>"#ffffff","background-color"=>"green")));
```

Comment: Do you have any code? Have you tried doing this before asking? Please improve your question. Code example would help

Comment: $dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders");

$dg->set_conditional_format("orderNumber","CELL",array(
    "condition"=>"eq","value"=>"10107","css"=> array("color"=>"#ffffff","background-color"=>"green")));

that is in documentation and i have tried this

$dg->set_conditional_format("orderNumber","CELL",array(
    "condition"=>"eq","value"=>$dg->columns['orderNumber'] ,"css"=> array("color"=>"#ffffff","background-color"=>"green")));

but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

What is `$dg->columns['orderNumber']`?? I could not find it mentioned anywhere in their [online documentation](https://phpgrid.com/documentation/).

My guess is that you are trying to compare values among columns. You can take a look at their `OnGridLoadComplete` event handler examples:

- https://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/909546-conditional-format-compare-two-cells
- https://phpgrid.com/example/row-level-permission-edit-condtion/